# How can I create clickable table rows which route to the same partial in angular?

Tags: angularjs, routes

I am new to AngularJS. 
I fetch some items from a server into a table. 
Now I want to be able to click on any table row and then route to a specific partial. (let's name it item-info)
I also want my route to change to something like "#/{{item.name}}". I don't want to specify my route name each time because I don't know which row the user clicks on. 
Also I don't want to lose which item the user clicked on in the previous page. I need the 'item.name' element.

I'm not sure if I should use ng-click or a simple  tag that has href="#/item.name".

```
<td><a href="#/item-info">{{item.name}}</a> </td>
```

Thanks,

Comment: ng-click, since you want to do more than just change routes

Comment: ok, can you explain more? If I use ng-click="go()" (does it have an argument or not?) how should I define the $scope.go function in my controller in order to be able to route to a url I want?

Comment: ng-click= "go($event)" -  function go($event) { var href = angular.element($event.target).attr("href"); ... }

Comment: thanks for this answer, but can you be more specific about href? if I want to route to "/test" where should I put it? cause `attr("/test");}` didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <td><a ng-click="onclick($event)" href="#/item-info">{{item.name}}</a> </td>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $location) {
   $scope.onclick = function($event) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        // do extra stuff
        var href =  angular.element($event.target).attr('href');
        $location.path(href);
   }); 
});
```

Comment: doesn't work. When I click nothing happens. I am trying to do this via $routeParams.item-id so that I can put my url as "#/:item-id". But this approach also doesn't work and when I click nothing happens :(

Comment: I would recommend getting your initial achor link to work **without** ng-click first, and then try this approach after.

Answer (score 0):

Finally could do it by having an ng-href for my click action like this:

`ng-href="#/{{item.id}}"`

then in my routeProvider:

`$routeProvider.when('/:id', {templateUrl: 'item-detail.html', controller: 'ItemDetailController'});`

and then in my ItemDetailController I use `$routeParams.id` to access exactly what will be shown in the url (this takes the ":id" part as shown in the routeProvider)

Now the problem I had with it though was that instead of writing `$routeProvider.when('/:id',` in the provider I wrote `$routeProvider.when('/:item-id',` and somehow the dash character messed it up!!
I removed it and now the `$routeParams.id` is known to my program and I use it.